After login, all my users are getting navigated to an app that is NOT their default app
I have an app called 'D&B Optimiser'. This is NOT marked as default for any profile.
Yet, my users complain that the post-login default screen that they see if this every time.
I checked the default app of the profiles and can see that it is 'standard__Sales'. When I checked the navigation on the browser logs, I can see that the navigation to DNB__tabName was via the org endpoint itself, meaning the navigation happened after login.
I fail to understand what this is happening. Any advice or guidance would be great!

Can you check Customize My Pages?, Click on settings under username on top right side-->Quick Find--->Customize My Pages-->Change My Display.

hi Vinay, not this is not it either. The network logs shows that the navigation automatically redirects to the page in question. It is happening from preLoadActions of the home page.

So the behaviour is such that the preference is always given to the last app visited at the time of logout. This takes preference over the default app mentioned in the profile. Users will need to logout from the app which they want to default the next time they login.

Just to add, the object where this details are captured is called 'UserAppInfo'. Updating this record for affected users with the new AppDefinitionId will resolve the issue when they log back in to the org.
